# How to add an overlay/stamp to a PDF file in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Does anyone know how to programmatically add a overlay or stamp to a PDF file in PHP? So far the best I've come up with is calling the [PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) library with the exec command. I'd prefer an actual PHP method if one exists.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913934/how-i-can-add-watermark-to-existing-pdf-file-using-php

Comment: If you can afford the licensing fee, [PDFlib](http://pdflib.com) is quite nice.

Comment: I looked at that post wanovak, but couldn't figure it out.  Now I took a closer look and that is working for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Marc, but we could never afford something like that for such a small project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question but I hope to help someone looking for this answer.

I have successfully used FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org), a free PHP library.

I have cut this code from a big function, please pay attenction to the missing variables that I couldn't include here.

```
        $pdf = new FPDI();

        // Number of pages of the PDF
        $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($source."/".$pdfList[$i]);

        // Loop the PDF's pages
        for($page_index=0; $page_index < $pagecount; $page_index++)
        {

            $tplidx = $pdf->importPage(($page_index+1), '/MediaBox');
            $pdf->addPage();
            $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);

            // Do I need to stamp this page? This is a boolean flag calculated from the settings for each page.
            $stampThis = false;

            if($settings->pages == 'all') 
            {
                $stampThis = true;
            }
            else if($settings->pages == 'last')
            {
                if($pagecount == $page_index+1)
                {
                    $stampThis = true;
                }
            }
            else if($settings->pages == 'first')
            {
                if($page_index == 0)
                {
                    $stampThis = true;
                }
            }
            else if($settings->pages == 'odd')
            {
                if($page_index%2 == 0)
                {
                    $stampThis = true;
                }
            }
            else if($settings->pages == 'even')
            {
                if($page_index%2 != 0)
                {
                    $stampThis = true;
                }
            }           

            // Stamp the PDF, in case the flag is true
            if($stampThis)
            {
                // Custom stamp
                if(!empty($settings->imageURL)) {

                    $pdf->Image($settings->imageURL, 
                                $settings->stamp_coord_x,
                                $settings->stamp_coord_y);
                }

            } // stamp if end

        } // pages loop end

      $pdf->Output($destination.'/'.$pdfList[$i], 'F');
```

Comment: Thanks!  Not working on that project anymore, so I can't test.  But it looks good to me!