# Add background watermark to pdf files via PHP for existing .pdf files?

Tags: php, linux, windows, pdf

I have a request from a client which requires me to process pdf files they upload. They upload pdf files and I search the pdf files for certain patterns and am supposed to add specific watermarks under certain conditions. Is there a way via php to open a pdf file, and add the background image and save it upon uploading?

Example:
Uploaded pdf file contains the word "Hello".. (add a smiley face background to pdf pages)

Uploaded pdd file contains "hey!" (add company logo as background for pdf pages)

Greatly appreciate your input! Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913934/how-i-can-add-watermark-to-existing-pdf-file-using-php/19540612#19540612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with FPDF and this add-on http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/9/

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for 3+ hours for something like this now

Comment: One thing to add/ask, I can see it can be done with text, but I'm clueless as to how to do it with images, do you have an example syntax with this rotate function/add on?

Comment: Go to http://www.fpdf.org then to manual and look for the `image` section. There you will find all the info about image manipulation. I would make a half-transparant image and place that on the page, so you can read the original text, even when the 'watermark' is placed above it...