# Add text/image watermark on existing pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, watermark

i have a pdf without water mark in my directory and i do not want to show the file structure because of this i used readfile($path); method,

Now i am unable to apply watermark on pdf before it displaying.

i have tried several ways like pdf to test parser but this did not solve my problem

Below the code i am using in php

```
ob_clean();
flush();
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
@readfile($path);
exit;
```

Comment: You must edit the PDF before sending it, check [How can I add a watermark to an existing PDF file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913934/how-can-i-add-a-watermark-to-an-existing-pdf-file-using-php)

Comment: Thanks for answering but it did not solve my problem,PlaceWatermark("filename.pdf", "This is a lazy, but still simple test\n This should stand on a new line!", 30, 120, 100,TRUE); this function used simple text(This is a lazy, but still simple test\n This should stand on a new line!) but i have to put watermark on already existing pdf

Comment: Any one can suggest paid library to add text/image watermark on existing PDF.